# Region/Country portion of address not displaying in some browsers

Tags: checkout, address

On a mostly fresh installation on Magento 2.1.3, when a user fills out their shipping address in the checkout flow, `<!-- ko text: address().region --` does not display a State.

In Chrome 55 the state displays great:

In Safari, both the country (United States) and any applicable state selected are missing from both the shipping and billings addresses that are displayed:

[image: safari]

There are no console errors, but just blank values where these would be expected.

[image: elements]

Where can I start looking to debug this? One of my users has also been able to repro on Chrome in Windows, which makes it even less clear to me what is going on.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing region: address().region to address().state